# sump up of setting up amp-jekyll in my project

Tags: plugins, jekyll, amp-html

I am working on a jekyll project and already asked some questions on stackoverflow and jekyll talks site. This post is a sump up for the issue I have about setting up amp-jekyll. amp-Jekyll is a jekyll plugin. The full documentation is at this adress : https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll

The tree of my project is the following

[image]

My Version of jekyll is jekyll-3.6.2
I installed the plugin using the Gemfile (gem "amp-jekyll", "1.0.2"  # installed). I checked that the plugin is well installed.
Then I followed the documentation:
1) I Placed the layout file (amp.html at https://github.com/juusaw/amp-jekyll/blob/master/amp.html) to the _layouts folder. I have a first question about that. I looked at this file and don't know how to use it. Have I just to copy it in the _layouts folder and that's all or have I to take a part of it and copy it to another file (and if so where ?). I can see in the body part the use of `{{ header | amp_images }}` or `{{ footer | amp_images: false, 24, 24 }}`. What does that mean ? . And what about the part included in head tag ?
2) Then, I Added amphtml-link to post heads (Add CSS styles to the html template). In my case I just copy the following code

```
{% if page.path contains '_posts' %}
  <link rel="amphtml" href="https://localhost::4000/inger/toto.html">
{% endif %}
```

with a faked href url in my footer.html file (https://github.com/flamant/fileshare/blob/master/footer.html).. I have a second question about this snippet of code. What is this link ? and is it taken into consideration if this page a post ?
3) And I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

The first page witch is published is index.html. the code is

```
---
layout: default
title: Hank Quinlan, Horrible Cop
lang: fr
---
<div class="blurb">
    <h1>This is content</h1>
</div>
```

The default.html file (in _layouts folder) is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% include header.html %}

{{ content }}

{% include footer.html %}
```

And the header.html is at the following location : https://github.com/flamant/fileshare/blob/master/header.html
The first images that I display (and that I can't see) are in this file.
So my main question is : Why I can't see the images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found what was going wrong : the attribute should be src instead of scr. I am confused about asking this question.